# How do fetch a JSON file when it does not have no parent?

Tags: javascript, json, file, parent

Example of JSON file (Hello.json):

```
[
{
    "Name": "Alex Smith",
    "User": "1234",
    "Description": "Blue eyes"
},
{
```

This is what I have:

```
fetch('Hello.json')
.then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
})
.then(function (data) {
    var information = data.name[0];
    $('#information').append(information);
```

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong or if there is a better way to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: `data` is a list containing objects. you will need to navigate to the object first. `data[0].name` in place of `data.name[0]`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```js
var information = data[0].name;
```

You have an array of objects, so above should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That makes sense.